# Android: How can I tap my notification to go directly to specific screen?

Tags: java, android, push-notification, android-notifications

I am writing an android application that provides a notification function. This notification can display both in-app and outside-app.

The problem I have is when I'm in home screen or another application and my app have push notification, after tapping, my application killed itself and reopen again since the beginning (splash screen).

So how can I tap notification to access application in the current state and moreover, access specific screen I want.

I've tried something that may help but it does not work for mine.

```
public void showNotification(String title, String message){

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, importance);
            //Boolean value to set if lights are enabled for Notifications from this Channel
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            //Boolean value to set if vibration are enabled for Notifications from this Channel
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            //Sets the color of Notification Light
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.GREEN);
            //Set the vibration pattern for notifications. Pattern is in milliseconds with the format {delay,play,sleep,play,sleep...}
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[] {
                    500,
                    500,
                    500,
                    500,
                    500
            });

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        }

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        resultIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        resultIntent.putExtra("key", "chat");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
        builder.setContentTitle(title);
        builder.setContentInfo("info");
        builder.setContentText(message);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        builder.setShowWhen(true);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.car_icon);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
//        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

}
```

By the way, my logcat doesn't shows anything...

At least I want my app open in current state, don't killed itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you add below flags:

```
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
```